# multiDexEnabled do not work

Tags: android, gradle, dex, android-multidex

I have a rather large android project. The project still compiles, but when I try to compile tests I get an error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebugTest'.
trouble writing output: Too many method references: 70561; max is 65536.
You may try using --multi-dex option.
```

Ok, I found the multiDexEnabled property and added

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

in the

```
defaultConfig
```

Also I made my application extend

```
MultiDexApplication
```

But it did not change anything, I still get

```
Execution failed for task ':logic:dexDebugTest'.
trouble writing output: Too many method references: 70561; max is 65536.
You may try using --multi-dex option.
```

And it even explicitly shows me the dx comand without --multi-dex parameter

```
sdk/build-tools/21.1.1/dx --dex --output /build/intermediates/dex/test/debug --input-list=build/intermediates/tmp/dex/test/debug/libraryList.txt
```

Comment: Have you followed all the steps in https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this to your build.gradle

```
android{

...

afterEvaluate {
        tasks.matching {
            it.name.startsWith('dex')
        }.each { dx ->
            if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
                dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
            } else {
                dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
            }
        }
    }

...
}
```