# Android multiDexEnabled did not work issue

Tags: android

I meet a strange issue.
I got 'The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.’ yesterday, after changing my code in submodule from java to kotlin.
My app works just fine before change code, and it's build.gradle looks like:

```
 defaultConfig {
      ...
      //multiDexEnable true // spelling error has been corrected
      multiDexEnabled true
      ...
    }
    dependencies {
      ...
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
      ...
    }
```

And my package structure like:
App .
--sharemodule .
--othermodule .
The sharemodule and the othermodule are submodules of my App.

I just reduced some unused code in sharemodule, and change its code to kotlin, then here comes this problem.
Please help me, thanks.

Thanks for the reply, I've corrected the spelling error. Also the App is extended the 'MultiDexApplication'

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication  {
```

And I've tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883649/multidexenabled-do-not-work), but did not work.

Should I also add 'multiDexEnabled true' to module's build.gradle? Currently I just add this to my app's build.gradle.
[image]

Comment: Please check `gradle plugin version` in your project-level `build.gradle` which is not outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `multiDexEnabled` NOT `multiDexEnable`. So make change in your **defaultConfig** in gradle file.

Current:

```
defaultConfig {
      ...
      multiDexEnable true
      ...
    }
```

Change to:

```
defaultConfig {
      ...
      multiDexEnabled true
      ...
    }
```

Check out this link for more information: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Read this link to understand more about **Enable Multidex for Apps with Over 64K Methods** : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: @Cheng, did you check my answer?

Comment: Thanks for reply, sir, but it didn't work. Still shows exceed 64k.

Comment: @Cheng, add your android studio logs screenshot as well.

Comment: @Cheng, check here the if you are following steps: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-android/troubleshoot/android-app-exceeds-64k-multidex-limit `Try step 4.`

Answer (score 0):

Use **Multidex** like this:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

- Add gradle in your project
- Setting up your app project to use a multidex configuration requires that you make the following modifications to your app project, depending on the minimum Android version your app supports.

**like this**

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 15 
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
  }

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**Currently you use**

```
multiDexEnable true
```

**Change to**

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

it helps you try this.

Comment: Thanks for reply, sir, but it didn't work. Still shows exceed 64k.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this ->

**Step 1 :** Add this in your app level `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
    ...
}
```

**Step 2 :** Add this dependency to your app level `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    ...
}
```

**Step 3 :** Create class which `extends` `Application` class

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);
        mInstance = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public AppController() {
        super();
    }
}
```

**Step 4 :** Add this to `application` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
        android:name="com.relyfy.adapter.AppController"
        .... >
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. And I create 'App' class extends MultiDexApplication, So I think android has done the step 3 and 4 for me. But didn't work.

Comment: Actually I also follow these 4 steps in my project and working perfectly and I also have module projects in my project.

Comment: OK, I add 'android:name="com.***.App"' in 'application', but didn't work.